# Measurable functions on product measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $ (X,\mu) $ be a measure space, and consider $X \times X$ with the product measure $\mu \times \mu $. Consider two functions $f$ and $g$ defined on $X \times X$ such that:

1. $f$ is measurable.
2. For a.e. x, the function $y \to g(x,y)$ is measurable.
3. The function $\int g(x,y) dy$ is a measurable function of x.
4. For a.e. x, $\int f(x,y) dy = \int g(x,y) dy $.

Is this data sufficient to imply that $g$ is measurable as well? and that $f=g$ a.e.?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: PS If we discard $f$ from the question, so only $g$ is given and 2. and 3 are assumed, a counter-example is given in Rudin.

Comment: I posted a related but in my eyes more difficult question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378317/measurability-of-a-function-defined-on-a-product-measure-space-and-related-to-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Take $X = [-1,1]$, and $\mu$ to be Lebesgue measure $m$.  Let $E$ be a non-measurable subset of $[-1,1]$, and define $g$ by
$$g(x,y) = \begin{cases} 2\cos(\pi y), && x \in E \\
 \cos(\pi y), && x \notin E.
\end{cases}$$
For each $x$, we have that $y \mapsto g(x,y)$ is measurable, and in fact $\int_X g(x,y)\,dy = 0$, so properties 1-4 are satisfied with $f=0$.  But $g$ is not measurable: the set where $g > 1$ is $E \times (-\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$ which is not a measurable subset of the square.

Note also that even if $g$ is measurable and satisfies 1-4, it does not follow that $f=g$ almost everywhere: replace $E$ in the above example by $[0,1]$.

Moral: you can't learn very much about a function by looking at what you get after integrating out one variable.

Comment: Thanks. A bit harder question is- what if 3+4 hold for every $g\times \chi_E $ where $E$ is any measurable subset of the product ?