# Measurability of a function defined on a product measure space, and related to a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $ (X,\mu) $ be a standard measure space - so that we may assume that $X$ is the unit interval $[0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Consider $X \times X$ with the product measure $\mu \times \mu $ defined on the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions defined on $X \times X$ such that:

1. $f$ is measurable.
2. For a.e. $x$, the function $y \to g(x,y)$ is measurable.
3. For every measurable subset $E\subset X \times X$, we have 
   $$\int \chi _E \cdot f(x,y) d\mu(y) = \int \chi_E \cdot g(x,y) d\mu(y) $$ for a.e. $x$.

Is this data sufficient to imply that $g$ is measurable as well? and that $f=g$ a.e.?

This is a (hopefully more interesting) variant of my previous question [Measurable functions on product measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377620/measurable-functions-on-product-measures), which was answered in the negative by @Nate Eldredge (but the same example does not work in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359653/if-f-leftx-cdot-right-is-measurable-for-every-x-and-f-left-cdot-y-right/359795#359795), take a bijection of $[0, 1]$ whose graph has outer area one. Let $g$ be the characteristic function of this graph. Let $f$ be the constant function 0. Now all of your 1, 2, 3 above hold but the conclusions fail.

Comment: If you are the same [hot queen](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/72316/hot-queen), then you might want to visit [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I could not login from a different computer and posting an answer here requires you to give a name so I used my previous user name.

Comment: Thank you hot_queen. I understand how such an automorphism would be a counter-example. But could you please give a hint or a reference to how to construct it?

Comment: Try using transfinite induction.

Comment: The point of my previous comment was that you can have the two accounts merged, either yourself (if you still have access to the other computer) or by sending a request to the SE team.

Comment: I know. Blah blah blah.

Comment: I am not very good with transfinite induction. I accept your answer, but would still be happy to have a reference.